# Running check_plain after t

Tags: 6, forms

Will this be correct :

```
drupal_set_title(check_plain(t("Donation Details for Project: $project->title")))
```

I want all of the string to be translated when needed. Should call check_plain first then t or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6) first. [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6) should be applied to literal strings, not to variables and not to results of function calls. From the manual of [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6):

> Because [t](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)() is designed for handling code-based strings, in almost all
>   cases, the actual string and not a variable must be passed through
>   [t](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)().
>
> Extraction of translations is done based on the strings contained in
>   [t](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)() calls. If a variable is passed through [t](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)(), the content of the
>   variable cannot be extracted from the file for translation.

Answer (score 4):

This would be better:

> drupal_set_title(t("Donation Details for Project: @title"),
>   array('@title' => $project->title));

Taken from [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)

> Special variables called "placeholders" are used to signal dynamic
>   information in a string which should not be translated. Placeholders
>   can also be used for text that may change from time to time (such as
>   link paths) to be changed without requiring updates to translations.
>
> @variable, which indicates that the text should be run through
>   check_plain, to escape HTML characters. Use this for any output that's
>   displayed within a Drupal page.

Comment: Can't I myself add html meta chars in typed text by mistake?

Comment: What do you mean? Also, is $project->title a node title?

Comment: I mean inadvertently I can add html meta chars even in this text: Donation Details for Project: ..... Then your example will not take care of it.

Comment: Is all of the data user-supplied then?  I'm not sure I follow.  Maybe you could expand your question with your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Better call check_plain first it will escape the html tags.Then you convert them into whatever the language you want.

Comment: If you call t() first may be for some language, it will return **invalid UTF-8 characters**.Then you pass t() result string into check_plain() it will filter all invalid UTF-8 characters.

Comment: If t() returns an invalid UTF-8 character, the translation is broken and should be fixed.